# Store lines of text that result from shell command

Tags: python

Here is the code related to this section of the code:

```
command1 = '/usr/local/GMT5SAR/bin/ALOS_baseline ' + str(master_file) + ' ' + str(master_file)
print command1
p1 = Popen(command1, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
out,err = p1.communicate()
print out
```

My command is working properly. Here's a screenshot of my console.

[image]

I need to store the lines that say `lon_tie_point .....` and `lat_tie_point .....`. The issue i'm running into is that those lines aren't including in `out`, which is what i'm printing out. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: If the lines are red, doesn't it mean they're getting printed on `stderr` instead?

Comment: `if line.contains("tie_point")` this could work?

Comment: @Tagc You're right! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the lines containing the information you need are being printed on `stderr` instead of `stdout`. From the [`subprocess` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> subprocess.STDOUT
>
> Special value that can be used as the stderr argument to Popen and indicates that standard error should go into the same handle as standard output.

Based on this, I think the following might work:

```
command1 = '/usr/local/GMT5SAR/bin/ALOS_baseline ' + str(master_file) + ' ' + str(master_file)
print command1
p1 = Popen(command1, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
out,err = p1.communicate()
print out
```